# Error WatchConnectivity in Watchkit2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, apple-watch

I am trying to connect apple watch app with ios app using `WatchConnectivity`.

when I press a table row, I want to pas some value to ios app:

```
   override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    let object = DataArray[rowIndex] as RowData
        let name = ["name":object.name]

    print(object.name)

    do {
        try session?.updateApplicationContext(name)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

> the error: Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7005 "Device is not paired." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Device is not paired., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Pair the device with a Watch.

Comment: Does this happen if you reset & repair Apple Watch?

Comment: Did you finally find a solution?